# Keep in state tuition when relocating to another state

Tags: united-states, taxes, college, tuition

My wife and I have lived in NC state for more than 10 years. I enrolled in an online program in the state university for continuing education one year ago. And eventually I will get a degree in 3 or 4 years. We own a house in NC. We are NC state residents and I enjoy the in-state tuition.

Now the question is I might relocate to another state at the end of the year 2015 because of a career change. My wife will still live in NC. We will still keep our house and pay the property tax. I still want to take classes in the future. My question is whether I will still pay the in-state tuition?

Comment: I don't know enough to really answer this question, but you might consider checking residency requirements of the states themselves, and the university. [Not sure if this is your school](http://resdetermination.uncc.edu/residency-requirements), but others probably have similar documentation available.

Comment: @briantist, not this school but they are in the same NC high education system. The policy is almost same.

Answer (score -2):

If you keep your billing and mailing addresses the same then you could still qualify for in state tuition. Also, your state ID/driver's license needs to stay in NC. The only question remains is the ethical one... though if you still consider NC your home then even that is not an issue.